# Get a random row in a sheet, where column is a known value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains data like this:

```
id line   | idsector |sector | isSectorPrior |etc...
1         | 1        | east  | no
2         | 1        | east  | no   
3         | 1        | east  | yes
4         | 1        | east  | yes
5         | 2        | west  | yes
6         | 2        | west  | yes    
7         | 2        | west  | no
8         | 2        | west  | yes
```

I need to draw one line where `isSectorPrior` will be "yes", and then, when I have the row, get `id line` that is in the cell 1.

So here, it can choose row 3, 4, 5, 6, or 8.

I found a lot or samples, that uses the range [(an example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212330/vba-select-random-row-in-range-of-select), but they can return e.g. row number 7, even though it has a "no". This should not happen.

How can I specify, get a random row, but only where iSectorPrio is yes?

My current code, not so much because I didn't find anything that could match what I want :

```
'get a sheet to use and find a random row
Set tempSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
'loop 50 times, to draw 50 different lines
    For i = 1 To 50
'todo : get randow row, where IsSelectPrio is yes
'then do whatever I want with it, like write copy it in another sheet or a csv
    Next i
```

The difficulty here (for me) is, there is no particular range, all I found were using the range. And considering, thats in the first rows, it it not part of the table.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: I think it can be down using a UDF that returns a array of longs that contains the matching row ids. The UDF will take in a range of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches.

**Approach 1:** Get a random row number (e.g. using the code from [that other solution you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212330/vba-select-random-row-in-range-of-select)), then check if you have a "yes" on that row. If not, then get a new random number; repeat until you get a yes. (Warning: this will go into an infinite loop if you have no yes'es.)

**Approach 2:** Start by making a list of row numbers that have a yes; then pick a random one among those.

Comment: As I ask first, How much prior lines I ust Select, the first solution is not a problem with infinite loop. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I think you should try something, then show us what problem you're having so we can help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is finding the right range to pick a random row you can do this:

(If your worksheet has to look the same way it looks now, make a copy of it)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sortRangeRows As Integer
Dim lastRow, lastColumn As Integer

'Get sortRange

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set sortRangeRows = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

'Sort after isSectorPrior:
sortRangeRows.Sort Key1:=sortRangeRows(1, 4), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns

'Find the last row with a "yes" in it (not entirely sure about this piece of code)

lastRowYes = ws1.Cells.Find("yes", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Now you have your range of rows with a yes. 
HTH